# Lang Fundamentals of Differential Geomety definition of covariant derivative of a tensor field

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I'm reading Serge Lang's Fundamentals of Differential Geometry. In chapter VIII section 1, he
defines a covariant derivative as follows:

By a **covariant derivative** $D$ we mean an $\bf{R}$-bilinear map
$$D:\Gamma T(X)\times\Gamma T(X)\to\Gamma T(X),$$
denoted by $(\xi,\eta)\mapsto D_\xi\eta$, satisfying the two conditions:

**COVD 1.** (a) In the first variable $\xi$, $D_\xi\eta$ is Fu-linear.
(b) For a function $\varphi$, define $D_\xi\varphi=\xi\phi=\mathscr{L}_\xi\varphi$ to be the
Lie derivative of the function. Then in the second variable $\eta$, $D_\xi\eta$ is a
derivation. Thus (a) and (b) can be written in the form:
$$D_{\varphi\xi}\eta=\varphi D_\xi\eta\quad\text{and}\quad D_\xi(\varphi\eta)=(D_\xi\varphi)\eta+\varphi D_\xi\eta.$$
**COVD 2.** $D_\xi\eta-D_\eta\xi=[\xi,\eta].$

He then goes on:

Having defined $D_\xi$ on functions and vector fields, we may extend the definition to all
differential forms, or even to multilinear tensor fields.
Let $\omega$ be in $\Gamma L^r(T(X))$, i.e. $\omega$ is a multilinear tensor field on $X$,
*not necessarily alternating*. We define $D_\xi\omega$ by giving its value on vector fields
$\eta_1,\dots,\eta_r$, namely
\begin{equation*}
  (D_\xi\omega)(\eta_1,\dots,\eta_r)=\mathscr{L}_\xi(\omega(\eta_1,\dots,\eta_r))-
  \sum_{j=1}^r\omega(\eta_1,\dots,D_\xi\eta_j,\dots,\eta_r).
\end{equation*}

Now I get what he is trying to do, but I don't see how you can get away with defining
a multilinear tensor field globally by defining it on global vector fields. (By the way,
in the introduction to this chapter, $X$ is just a plain vanilla $C^\infty$ manifold, which
for Lang means modeled on some set of Banach spaces. $\Gamma T(X)$ is the $\mathbf{R}$-vector
space of vector fields, which happens to also be a module over the ring of functions Fu$(X)$. And finally, $\pi:TX\to X$ is the natural map of the tangent bundle to $X$.)

In (my take on) Lang's formalism, $\omega\colon X\to L^r_X(TX)$ where the fiber over $x$ is
$(L^r_X(TX))_x=\{x\}\times L^r(T_xX)$. Furthermore, if $(V,\psi)$ is a chart for $X$,
with $\psi\colon V\to\mathbf{E}$,
then we have a trivializing map $\tau\colon\pi^{-1}(V)\to V\times\mathbf{E}$ for $\pi$ and
a trivializing map $\gamma\colon L^r_X(\pi)^{-1}(V)\to V\times L^r(\mathbf{E})$
for the vector bundle $L^r_X(\pi)\colon L^r_X(TX)\to X$. To be a section, $\omega(x)$
needs to be in $L^r_X(\pi)^{-1}(x)$, so if $x\in V$, then with
$\gamma_x=\text{pr}_2\circ\gamma|L^r_X(\pi)^{-1}(x)$, we need
$\gamma_x(\omega(x))\in L^r(\mathbf{E})$. So if we are defining $D_\xi\omega$, we need
$\gamma_x(D_\xi\omega(x))\in L^r(\mathbf{E})$.

Now, on page 124 (Chapter V section 3) Lang indicates that for vector fields
$\xi_1,\dots,\xi_r$ defined on an open subset $U$ of $X$,
$\langle\omega,\xi_1\times\dots\times\xi_r\rangle$ is a function on $U$, whose value at
$x\in U$ is $\omega(x)(\xi_1(x),\dots,\xi_r(x))$. In my take on Lang's formalism
this would actually equal $(\gamma_x(\omega(x)))(\tau_x(\xi_1(x)),\dots,\tau_x(\xi_r(x)))$,
where $\tau_x=\text{pr}_2\circ\tau|\pi^{-1}(x)$. [I admit that I am glossing over the fact
that $\xi_i$ is a vector field on $U$, which means it maps to $TU$. For a modicum of
simplicity, I'm just assuming that $\xi_i$ maps $U$ to $TX$, which I don't think will hurt.]
So I assume this is what Lang means by $(D_\xi\omega)(\eta_1,\dots,\eta_r)$, except that
it seems we have to assume that $\eta_j$ is a vector field on $X$, since Lang has not
given a definition for $D_\xi\eta_j$ when $\xi\in\Gamma T(X)$ but $\eta_j\in\Gamma T(U)$.
But since $\gamma_x(\omega(x))\in L^r(\mathbf{E})$, we need to specify the value of
$\gamma_x(\omega(x))$ on every $(v_1,\dots,v_r)\in\mathbf{E}^r$. And that would mean that
given $v_j\in\mathbf{E}$, we would need to be able to exhibit a *global* vector field
$\xi_j$ such that $\tau_x(\xi_j(x))=v_j$. I know how to make a local vector field
$\xi^V_j\colon V\to TV$ or even mapping to $TX$ which sends $x$ to $\tau^{-1}(x,v_j)$,
but I don't know how to globalize it to all of $X$.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to define a vector field $\xi:X\to TX$ such that its
local representation in a chart $(V,\psi)$ at a given point $\psi x$ is $v\in\mathbf{E}$?
Do I have to assume
something like $X$ admitting partitions of unity subordinate to a particular open covering
in order to do so? If that is the case, how do you use the partition of unity to do it?

Comment: I haven't read your whole question carefully, but for the last part, you need to assume that the model Banach spaces have norms which are $C^r$ away from the origin (this is of course true for Hilbert spaces). Because under this condition, we can construct bump functions; i.e a function $f_{r_1,r_2, a}:E\to \Bbb{R}$, where $0<r_1<r_2$ and $a\in E$ such that $f_{r_1,r_2,a}$ is equal to $1$ on $B_{r_1}(a)$, the open ball of radius $r_1$ centered at $a$, and equal to $0$ outside $B_{r_2}(a)$.

Comment: Because then, you can take the constant vector field $v\in E$, multiply by a bump function so that the support lies inside $\psi[V]$. Now, you have a local vector field $\xi:V\to TV\subset TX$, and you can extend it to be $0$ outside $V$, and it will be smooth.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I believe you are correct about needing that assumption. So let's assume the norm on the model space(s) is $C^\infty$ away from the origin. Then I can create the necessary vector fields and thereby define $D_\xi\omega$. But the definition depends on the choice of chart and bump function. I know how to show that the bump function choice doesn't matter, but I have two problems left. I don't know how to show that the definition is independent of the choice of chart, and I don't know how to show that the resulting map is multilinear continuous (the multilinear part is easy).

Comment: in finite-dimensions, $C^{\infty}$-linearity wrt $\xi$ and product rule relative to $\eta$ implies that $D_{\xi}\eta$ at a point $p$ depends only on the values of $\xi,\eta$ at $p$ and in a neighborhood of $p$ respectively. But the proof I know uses a basis, so doesn't generalize immediately. If I'm right your followup question is really about why we can identify $C^{\infty}$ multilinear maps (in the infinite-dimensional case) with smooth sections of the tensor bundle. For this, I'd suggest you take a look at Abraham Marsden and Ratiu's book (Chapter 6.2,6.4; it's all proven there carefully)

Comment: I tried to study AMR before posting. Their take on covariant derivatives is to assume you have a spray associated with a metric and define the covariant derivative from the bilinear form of the spray. Lang turns it around and defines a covariant derivative first, then one derived from a spray, and finally there's the spray of a metric. The problem I have is in the extension of that initial definition of covariant derivative to tensor fields. He defines it by giving its value on a collection of vector fields on the manifold, and its value is a function. This is where I'm having problems.

Comment: The closest thing in AMR to this is 6.2.20, which (assuming the model space(s) have $C^\infty$ norms away from the origin) gives an isomorphism between the space defined just prior to 6.2.20 and ordinary tensor fields, which is very close to what I would need in the Lang method. However, I have the same two problems with the AMR proof of 6.2.20 that I mentioned in my earlier comment. I can't see how to get the multilinear maps to be continuous and I can't see how to get the definition to be chart-independent. They talk about how to get the definition to be bump-function independent, and I've

Comment: verified that works.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I just posted a question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4180409/527829 about this last point.