# Help verifying proof about tensor fields in Abraham, Marsden, Ratiu, Manifolds, Tensor Analysis, and Applications

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

This question is apropos of a comment I received in the question: [Lang Fundamentals of Differential Geomety definition of covariant derivative of a tensor field](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4152638/527829). The comment referred to a proposition in Abraham, Marsden, Ratiu, Manifolds, Tensor Analysis, and Applications (hereafter AMR). In the second edition, it is Proposition 5.2.20 and in the third edition it is Proposition 6.2.20. A complete
understanding of the AMR proposition would be useful in addressing the referred to
question.

**Proposition.** Let $M$ be a finite-dimensional manifold or be modeled on a Banach space
with norm $C^\infty$ away from the origin. Then $\mathcal{T}^r_s(M)$ is isomorphic to
$\mathfrak{T}^r_s(M)$ regarded as $\mathcal{F}(M)$-modules and as real vector spaces. In particular $\mathfrak{X}^*(M)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{X}^*(M)$.

[Before citing the proof, here are the definitions given just before the proposition:

$$L_{\mathcal{F}(M)}(\mathfrak{X}(M),\mathcal{F}(M))=\mathcal{X}^*(M)$$
the $\mathcal{F}(M)$-linear mappings on $\mathfrak{X}(M)$, and similarly
\begin{equation*}
  \mathfrak{T}^r_s(M)=L^{r+s}_{\mathcal{F}(M)}(\mathcal{X}^*(M),\dots,\mathfrak{X}(M);
  \mathcal{F}(M))
\end{equation*}
the $\mathcal{F}(M)$-multilinear mappings.

I'm pretty certain there is a typo (theirs, not mine) in that last display. It would make far more sense if the definition was
\begin{equation*}
  \mathfrak{T}^r_s(M)=L^{r+s}_{\mathcal{F}(M)}(\mathfrak{X}^*(M),\dots,\mathfrak{X}(M);
  \mathcal{F}(M))
\end{equation*}
where all I did was change the font from calligraphic to fraktur on the first of the
$r+s$ elements listed. This same typo exists in both the second and third editions. I'll assume this latter display is the correct one.]

**Proof.** Consider the map $\mathcal{T}^r_s(M)\to\mathfrak{T}^r_s(M)$ given by
\begin{equation*}
  \ell(\alpha^1,\dots,\alpha^r,X_1,\dots,X_s)(m)=\ell(m)(\alpha^1(m),\dots,X_s(m)).
\end{equation*}
[EDIT: It seems to me that it would make more sense notationally
if the right hand side $\ell$ was actually $t$.]

This map is clearly $\mathcal{F}(M)$-linear. To show it is an isomorphism, given such
a multilinear map $\ell$, define $t$ by
\begin{equation*}
  t(m)(\alpha^1(m),\dots,X_s(m))=\ell(\alpha^1,\dots,X_s)(m).
\end{equation*}

To show that $t$ is well-defined we first show that, for each $v_0\in T_mM$, there is
an $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ such that $X(m)=v_0$, and similarly for dual vectors. Let
$(U,\phi)$ be a chart at $m$ and let $T_m\varphi(v_0)=(\varphi(m),v_0')$.
Define $Y\in\mathfrak{X}(U')$ by $Y(u)=(u',v_0')$ on a neighborhood $V_1$ of
$\varphi(m)$, where $w=\varphi(n)$. [I have to believe there are a couple of AMR
typos there. I think the $w=\varphi(n)$ was probably supposed to be $u'=\varphi(u)$,
but in any case, it should not be needed, since $Y$ is supposed to be defined on
$U'$, which I assume is $\varphi(U)$, so the definition of $Y$ should, I believe,
read $Y(u')=(u',v_0')$.] Extend $Y$ to $U'$ so $Y$ is zero outside $V_2$, where
$\mathrm{cl}(V_1)\subset V_2$, $\mathrm{cl}(V_2)\subset U'$, by means of a bump
function. Define $X$ by $X_\varphi=Y$ on $U$, and $X=0$ outside $U$. Then $X(m)=v_0$.
The construction is similar for dual vectors.

As in Theorem 4.2.16 [same number in both second and third editions],
$\mathcal{F}(M)$-linearity of $\ell$ shows that the definition of $t(m)$ is
independent of how the vectors $v_0$ (and corresponding dual vectors) are extended
to fields.

The proof goes on from there to prove smoothness and to give a simplification in
the finite-dimensional case.

I have two problems with this proof:

1. I don't see how to show that the definition of $t$ (given $\ell$) is independent of
   the choice of chart $(U,\varphi)$. The referenced 4.2.16 only gives an example of how to
   prove that a particular definition is independent of the specifics of the bump function
   used to define it. It doesn't deal with independence from the choice of chart.
2. I don't see how to show that $t(m)$ is continuous (multilinear). The multilinear
   part is easy; it's the continuous part that I can't figure out.

EDIT: It occurs to me that if this proposition is going to be true,
then the meaning of
$L^{r+s}_{\mathcal{F}(M)}(\mathfrak{X}^*(M),\dots,\mathfrak{X}(M);\mathcal{F}(M))$ has to be more than the stated
"$\mathcal{F}(M)$-multilinear mappings". It seems that from the forward
direction of the isomorphism we are going to have that
\begin{equation*}
  |\ell(\alpha^1,\dots,X_s)(m)|
  =|(t(m))(\alpha^1(m),\dots,X_s(m))|
  \leq||t(m)||\,||\alpha^1(m)|| \cdots ||X_s(m)||
\end{equation*}
so I think this condition should be part of the definition of
$L^{r+s}_{\mathcal{F}(M)}(\mathfrak{X}^*(M),\dots,\mathfrak{X}(M);\mathcal{F}(M))$. That is, I think we should define
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
  L^{r+s}_{\mathcal{F}(M)}(&\mathfrak{X}^*(M),\dots,\mathfrak{X}(M);\mathcal{F}(M))=\\
  &\{\mathcal{F}(M)\text{-multilinear }\mathcal{F}(M)\text{-valued}\,\ell:
  \forall m\in M,\exists c(m)\geq 0\text{ such that}\\
  &|(\ell(\alpha^1,\dots,X_s))(m)|\leq c(m)||\alpha^1(m)||\cdots||X_s(m)||\}.
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Of course, we will have to specify, for each $m$, a norm of $T_m(M)$
and for $(T_m(M))^*$. I think this will take care of question 2. That
still leaves question 1: showing chart-independence.

Comment: Agree w. u on fraktur instead of cal, and $t$ instead of $\ell$ on RHS. Regarding duals see caveat in AMR intro \S 6.1 pg. 341 \"$E^*$ we will mean another Banach space weakly paired to $E$; it need not be the full functional analytic dual of $E$. In particular, $E^{**}$ will always be chosen to be $E$. A bit unsatisfactory...

Comment: @p.co I agree that the AMR comment about $E^**$ being *chosen* to be $E$ is not particularly satisfactory. I don't think the assumption of self-duality of $E$, as mentioned in FDG, applies here since there is no mention in this AMR proposition of a pseudo-Riemannian metric. I'm beginning to believe that AMR's failure to mention anything that would help prove continuity of the multilinear maps is an oversight in the translation from the finite dimensional case (where it is automatic). I think that comment might also apply to the referenced FDG question.

Comment: Quite a few things seem to be glossed over. There probably is a correct topology on the $L^{r+s}_{\mathcal{F}(M)}(\mathfrak{X}^*(M),\dots,\mathfrak{X}(M);\mathcal{F}(M))$ as some LCTVS (Frechet?). Maybe Kriegl-Michor might be the book to look for details.

Comment: Regarding your Q1 (indep of chart) instead of AMR's "As in thm 4.2.16, F(M)-linearity of ℓ shows that the definition of t(m) is independent of how the vectors v0..." I found it better to show $\ell$ is local using $\mathcal{F}(M)$ linearity in place of the Leibniz rule (cf. proof that $\theta$ is local in thm 4.2.16).